# Unity Linux package export is modifying my DLL

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, dll, command-line

Just to give some context, I'm trying to create a build server on Ubuntu 16.04 to build a package for the Unity Asset store.

I'm using mcs to export some of our code (the code that we don't want user facing) into a dll, using the following command:

```
mcs -debug+ -debug:full -optimize- -codepage:utf8 -sdk:2 -lib:/opt/Unity/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/2.0-api/ -t:library -define:DEBUG -define:RELEASE_IS_TRIAL -define:DEBUGGER_IS_DISABLED  -out:<path to dll> -reference:<required extra references> -recurse:<path to source>/*.cs
```

I then put this inside a new unity project and export that project using the following command:

```
/opt/Unity/Editor/Unity -quit -batchmode -nographics -serial <serial> -username <username> -password "" -projectPath <path to project> -exportPackage "Assets" <path to preferred output location>.unitypackage
```

If I then import this package in unity on windows, I get a bunch of errors along the lines of:

```
The type or namespace name A does not exist in the namespace B (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Here A and B are my own defined types and namespaces.. i.e. the dll is not being loaded. There's nothing wrong with this dll though. In particular, if i run the above mcs command, take that output dll and replace the one in the imported package, everything imports fine. If i look at the Assembly attributes of the dll as it was exported in the unitypackage, and the dll straight from mcs (using ILSpy), I can see that the one exported by unity has an extra attribute:

```
[assembly: UnityAPICompatibilityVersion("5.6.0xb10Linux")]
```

I'm highly suspicious that this is the attribute causing the problem, but I don't know how to stop Unity from exporting the dll this way so that the unitypackage can be platform agnostic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a later version of Unity running on the Linux machine than on my Windows machine. There were incompatibility errors in the code because I was using obsolete functions from the Unity API as far as the Linux machine was concerned. So when it built the package it created a screwy dll. Whoops.